# Searching in a linked list

Tags: c, recursion, multidimensional-array, linked-list

First I want to thank all of you that will answer this problem.

**the problems are on edit**

The problem is this, I have to create a C program that generates a maze from a .txt file, inside the .txt file we have the number of rows and columns and the labyrinth scheme (I will append a file as a reference here).

20  // number of rows

20  // number of columns

labyrinth scheme **that can change**

```
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
X     X    X       X
X XXXXX XXXX XXX XXX
X       X      X X X
X XXXXXXXXXXXX X X X
X X   X        X X X
X XXX XXXXXX XXXXX X
X XXX    X X X     X
X    XXX       XXXXX
X XXX   XXXXXX     X
X   XXX X X    X X X
XXX XXX X X XXXX X X
X     X X   XX X X X
XXXXX     XXXX X XXX
X     X XXX    X   X
X XXXXX X XXXX XXX X
X X     X  X X     X
X X XXXXXX X XXXXX X
X X                X
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX X
```

The X's are walls.

The player is * and **it starts in position (1,1) and the exit is always in (18,19)**

Inside the code there are 3 structures:

1. Position represents a position inside the labyrinth grid
2. The cell is a structure that describes which character is present in
   position pos of the grid. The structure makes available the visited
   Boolean variable useful when searching for the exit path from the
   maze, the variable expresses the fact that the search has already
   visited or not that particular position of the grid.
3. The node structure must be used to create the linked list that
   contains a viable road to exit the maze.

```c
typedef struct{
    int x, y;
} position;

typedef struct{     
    pos;
    char ch;
    bool visited;
} cell;

typedef struct {
    position pos;
    struct node *next;
} node;
```

This is the function where I found some problems.

```
node *search(cell *grid, position pos, position goal, int rows, int columns)
```

This function has to search recursively a viable road to the exit that is in (18,19) using also a function `bool isEmpty` to see if a node is empty

```c
bool isEmpty(node *list) {
    if(list ->  next== NULL) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

I thought that this function may be like this

```
node *search(cell *grid, position pos, position goal, int rows, int columns){
 node* new_node = (node)malloc(sizeof(node));

 //if the last element equals goal position the search finishes
 if (new_node->pos.x == goal.x && new_node->pos.y == goal.y ) {
    return new_node;
 } else {
    return  *search(cell *grid, position pos, position goal, int rows, int columns);
 }
}
```

But when I run the program it crashes. How can I fix this search?

**[EDIT]**

First of all i cant change the structures because is a project specification.

The function

```
node *search(cell *grid, position pos, position goal, int rows, int columns)
```

has to a recursive algorithm to identify the road to the cell (18,19) //the exit
This funtion has to return a linked list of positions that the player (*) must visit in order to exit. The return value (which will be suitably saved in the main) will therefore be the head node of this linked list this funtion uses 2 more funtions:

1)

```
bool isEmpty(node∗ list)
```

this funtion returns true if the list is empty otherwise false

2)

```
 node∗ push_list (node∗ list , position pos)
```

this is a classic push function for the managment of the list. It adds in the head of the list a new node that contains the position pos

Down here there is the code that i have made

```
node *search(cell *grid, position pos, position goal, int rows, int columns)
{

//base case
    if(pos.x == goal.x && pos.y == goal.y)
    {
        //dont know how to return the position cause im in a multidimentional array

    }

}


   bool isEmpty(node *list)
{

    if(list ->  next== NULL)
    {
        return true;

    }else{

        return false;
    }

}
```

this is how i save the maze

```
cell *read_grid(char *filename, int *rows, int *columns)
```

{

```
int i,j;

//steam file
FILE *fp;




fp = fopen("grid.txt", "r+");


fscanf(fp, "%d\n%d\n", rows, columns);
fprintf(stdout, "%d\n%d\n", *rows, *columns);

cell grid[*rows][*columns];
cell *temp = (cell*)malloc(sizeof(cell));

assert(*grid != NULL);

if(fp == NULL)
{

    printf("error\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

}




for(i = 0; i < *rows; i++)
{

    for(j = 0; j < *columns; j++)
    {
        fscanf(fp, "%c", &(grid[i][j]).ch);
        grid[i][j].pos.x =i;
        grid[i][j].pos.y =j;

    }
    fscanf(fp, "\n");
}




fclose(fp);

temp = *grid;
return temp;
```

}

Comment: `new_node->pos.x` trying to access not initialized memory

Comment: What do you mean by `return  *search(cell *grid, position pos, position goal, int rows, int columns);`. You are calling the function, not defining it. Also, can you show the `search()` function body?

Comment: Your basic structure setup looks wrong. From what you describe, your `struct node` should contain `cell` and `next` instead of just `pos` and `next`. That way you will have the remaining information for `ch` and `visited` available. Otherwise, you have no correlation between the current position and `visited` and `ch`. Keeping two separate lists seems to unnecessarily complicate things.

Comment: @kuro i edited the problem,  i hope it will be more useful now the explenation

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin  i edited the problem, i hope it will be more useful now the explenation

Comment: Okay, I'm still a little unclear, but if I understand your edit, you will have either an *array of struct cell* which defines the board, which char is in the cell and if it has been visited. You then need a linked list of `node` that successfully navigates through your collection of cells and exits at 18,19. What is it that holds the collection of cells? Array of struct? Do you have the code that declares and initializes that object? That would be helpful to know how to traverse it to fill your list of `node`.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin the collection of cells is inside cell grid that is a array of struct yes i thave that code if is helpful ill edit the post to make it more clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is pretty much exactly what you need I took the code from [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maze_generation_algorithm)! 
but slightly modified it to draw the maze to a test.txt file as you needed.I hope it helps.

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <time.h>
    #include <string.h>

    typedef struct
       {
        int x, y; 
        void *parent; //Pointer to parent node
        char c; //Character to be displayed
        char dirs; //Directions that still haven't been explored
       } Node;
       Node *nodes; 
       int width, height; //Maze dimensions


     int init( )
{
    int i, j;
    Node *n;

    //Allocate memory for maze
    nodes = calloc( width * height, sizeof( Node ) );
    if ( nodes == NULL ) return 1;

    //Setup crucial nodes
    for ( i = 0; i < width; i++ )
    {
        for ( j = 0; j < height; j++ )
        {
            n = nodes + i + j * width;
            if ( i * j % 2 ) 
            {
                n->x = i;
                n->y = j;
                n->dirs = 15; //Assume that all directions can be explored (4 youngest bits set)
                n->c = ' '; 
            }
            else n->c = '#'; //Add walls between nodes
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

Node *link( Node *n )
{
    //Connects node to random neighbor (if possible) and returns
    //address of next node that should be visited

    int x, y;
    char dir;
    Node *dest;

    //Nothing can be done if null pointer is given - return
    if ( n == NULL ) return NULL;

    //While there are directions still unexplored
    while ( n->dirs )
    {
        //Randomly pick one direction
        dir = ( 1 << ( rand( ) % 4 ) );

        //If it has already been explored - try again
        if ( ~n->dirs & dir ) continue;

        //Mark direction as explored
        n->dirs &= ~dir;

        //Depending on chosen direction
        switch ( dir )
        {
            //Check if it's possible to go right
            case 1:
                if ( n->x + 2 < width )
                {
                    x = n->x + 2;
                    y = n->y;
                }
                else continue;
                break;

            //Check if it's possible to go down
            case 2:
                if ( n->y + 2 < height )
                {
                    x = n->x;
                    y = n->y + 2;
                }
                else continue;
                break;

            //Check if it's possible to go left 
            case 4:
                if ( n->x - 2 >= 0 )
                {
                    x = n->x - 2;
                    y = n->y;
                }
                else continue;
                break;

            //Check if it's possible to go up
            case 8:
                if ( n->y - 2 >= 0 )
                {
                    x = n->x;
                    y = n->y - 2;
                }
                else continue;
                break;
        }

        //Get destination node into pointer (makes things a tiny bit faster)
        dest = nodes + x + y * width;

        //Make sure that destination node is not a wall
        if ( dest->c == ' ' )
        {
            //If destination is a linked node already - abort
            if ( dest->parent != NULL ) continue;

            //Otherwise, adopt node
            dest->parent = n;

            //Remove wall between nodes
            nodes[n->x + ( x - n->x ) / 2 + ( n->y + ( y - n->y ) / 2 ) * width].c = ' ';

            //Return address of the child node
            return dest;
        }
    }

    //If nothing more can be done here - return parent's address
    return n->parent;
}

void draw(FILE *fp)
{
    int i, j;

    //Outputs maze to terminal - nothing special
    for ( i = 0; i < height; i++ )
    {
        for ( j = 0; j < width; j++ )
        {
            fprintf(fp, "%c", nodes[j + i * width].c );
        }
        fprintf(fp, "\n" );
    }
}

int main( int argc, char **argv )
{
    Node *start, *last;

    //Check argument count
    if ( argc < 3 )
    {
        fprintf( stderr, "%s: please specify maze dimensions!\n", argv[0] );
        exit( 1 );
    }

    //Read maze dimensions from command line arguments
    if ( sscanf( argv[1], "%d", &width ) + sscanf( argv[2], "%d", &height ) < 2 )
    {
        fprintf( stderr, "%s: invalid maze size value!\n", argv[0] );
        exit( 1 );
    }
//Allow only odd dimensions
    if ( !( width % 2 ) || !( height % 2 ) )
    {
        fprintf( stderr, "%s: dimensions must be odd!\n", argv[0] );
        exit( 1 );
    }



    //Do not allow negative dimensions
    if ( width <= 0 || height <= 0 )
    {
        fprintf( stderr, "%s: dimensions must be greater than 0!\n", argv[0] );
        exit( 1 );
    }

    //Seed random generator
    srand( time( NULL ) );

    //Initialize maze
    if ( init( ) )
    {
        fprintf( stderr, "%s: out of memory!\n", argv[0] );
        exit( 1 );
    }

    //Setup start node
    start = nodes + 1 + width;
    start->parent = start;
      last = start;
      FILE *fptr;
      // use appropriate location if you are using MacOS or Linux
      fptr = fopen("./test.txt","w");   
      //Connect nodes until start node is reached and can't be left
      while ( ( last = link( last ) ) != start );
      draw(fptr);
   }
```